# php include not working on ipad

Tags: php

A website I manage was built using php. I use includes on every page to pull in the header, menu and footer. Over the weekend, the server was hacked. I deleted all the files on the server and uploaded fresh copies. After doing that, the site does not come up properly on the iPad. All files that are called using "include" are not showing up. They do, however, show up perfectly fine on my desktop.

As these are the exact same files that have been on the server for over a year and they always worked before on both the iPad and desktop, I'm at a complete loss as to what could be causing the iPad to suddenly be off.

Any thoughts? Is it possible the guy taking care of the server may have changed some setting on the server side or altered settings in php.ini to cause this issue?

Comment: The type of browser can't affect what PHP does. Are you sure you've cleared the cache? Did you try a different tablet?

Comment: Check that all paths in the `include` statements are still correct after the re-upload and that the re-uploaded files have the appropriate permissions. Also, there's a chance that your website is cached on your desktop browser which is why it still looks the same. Clear your cache to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, it's not cache on your desktop ? Maybe iPad is showing the right situation. Try to clear the cache of your browser in Desktop (or open an incognito session). If all includes disappear in desktop after that, it must be something wrong with your files. Try to re-upload again and check the permissions and include statements.

Comment: Ugh! Never considered that but yep, clearly it's a problem with the file itself. Still, it doesn't make sense. Why would it be ignoring the include statement? The only things at the very top of my file are a variable for the page title and then an include statement calling in the header.php file.

Comment: Actually, it's not ignoring. When browser have cache do display, it won't even call your code. It will see that there's an valid cached page from a moment before, where your files were ok, so it will display that cache instead hit your server.